# Many child processes communicating to single parent

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, posix

I need to try to have a single parent spawn and meaningfully communicate with multiple child processes. This means sending data and having them send data back to the single parent. To start off, I've just been trying to have my children output something and having my parent catch it with the ultimate goal of allowing 2-way communication between all children to the parent. To accomplish this, for each children I instantiated two pipes and I store all the pipes into a multidimensional array called `pipes`. The multidimensional pipes array stores such that each index `i` is for the `ith + 1` child and the `[i][0]` index has a pipe that is specifically for the `parent` to talk to the `child`, and the `[i][1]` index has a pipe that is specifically for the `child` to talk to the `parent`. The `children` processes are all very simple spawns that just execute this piece of code:

### foo.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("Hi there!");
    close(STDOUT_FILENO); //Close our write end
    close(STDIN_FILENO); //Close our read end
    //Else do nothing
    return 0;
}
```

My main code is located in this and it begins by creating all the necessary pipes (2 of them per children). I then `dup2` the `STDIN` and the `STDOUT` so the `printf` prints to the pipe I want it to.

#### fork_complex.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAXSIZE 4096
#define CHILDREN 5

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    //Needs command line arguments
    int ** pipes[CHILDREN]; //The multi-dimensional array that contains CHILDREN pipes
    //Allocate the space
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILDREN; i++) {
        //Each children will need two pipes, one for comunicating and one for writing
        pipes[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*) * 2);
        pipes[i][0] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); //This pipe is specifically parent to child
        pipes[i][1] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); //This pipe is for specifically for the child to parent

        //Create the pipes
        if (pipe(pipes[i][0]) == -1 || pipe(pipes[i][1]) == -1) {
            //There was a failure in generating one of the pipes
            perror("Error on generating the pipe");
        }
    }
    //Spawn the child processses
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILDREN; i++) {
        int status = fork(); //Fork a child
        switch (status) {
            case -1:
                perror("Failed to fork the process");
                exit(1);
                break;
            case 0:
                //Child process, exec the floor
                dup2(pipes[i][0][0], fileno(stdin));
                dup2(pipes[i][1][1], fileno(stdout));
                execl("./foo", "");
                break;
        }
        //Parent continues the loop to spawn more children
    }
    
    char readed[MAXSIZE] = ""; //Reading buffer
    //Now read back from the pipes
    for (int i = 0; i < CHILDREN; i++) {
        while (read(pipes[i][1][0], readed, MAXSIZE) > 0) {
            printf("From pipe %d, we have read %s\n", i, readed);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

However, it seems that my code is constantly stuck in the `while` block at the bottom to read from the pipes, as when I remove it, the code executes completely. I have a few guesses, possibly that we have zombie children (since they terminate before the parent may have gotten to the for loop). I'm not sure what happens to the pipe when the child dies (other then the file descriptors related to it are closed) and we can still read from it (I'm also very curious about this). However, in my past experience, it seems that you still can. I've been stuck at this problem for hours, any insights would be greatly appreciated (or what I could be doing wrong)!

Comment: It might actually be simpler to use sockets in this case. Much less file-descriptors to think about at the very least. Might take a little more code to set up, but once done it's as easy as reading from/writing to a pipe.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks for the suggestion, but I would like to learn more about `piping` and would like to try to do this with just pipes

Comment: Also regarding your code, are you sure that the "strings" you attempt to transmit between the processes are C-style strings, i.e. zero terminated? Otherwise you will have *undefined behavior* trying to print them in the parent process.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, does not `""` create null-terminated string in my `printf` statement?

Comment: You need to close all pipes before the `execl` call. Also close all write pipes before the last `for` loop.

Comment: You should be using `select` or `epoll` or something like that for IO multiplexing

Comment: You have to be careful through, pipes are *streams* of data, without any specific packet boundaries. While a write to a pipe will be atomic (in that either all data is pushed to the pipe, or the write call will fail) there are no boundaries in the actual data stream in the pipe, meaning one `read` call might not actually read all the data currently in the pipe, and you might have to use a loop to get all the data. The problem here is if you read some of the text sent, but not the part containing the string terminator.

Comment: To expand on jdarthenay's comment: the parent also needs to close all the write ends.  After you fork all the children, the parent needs to go through and close all the write ends or its reads will block forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `read` `4096` bytes, some systems (like linux) will try to satisfy the full request and will block until the other end has 1) written all `4096` bytes or 2) closed the write end.
All the duplicates of the write end need to be closed, and there isn't just one.
`dup`ing creates a new reference to a file descriptor. When you `fork`, it's as if you `dup`ed all filedescriptors you had open at that time.
For your `read` to finish, you either need to satisfy the full 4096byte request or generate an EOF and for the latter to happen, all the clones of the write end need to be closed.

Because each of your children execs, what you could do is set each pipe `O_CLOEXEC` (with `fcntl`), and `close` each write end in the parent after you've forked off the child that's going to write to the write end.

(Other then that, make sure to include all the headers you need and make sure you handle all errors).